# Как собрать messenger для Android

Tags: android

Добрый день.

У меня возник вопрос, с чего нужно начать разработку messenger для Аndroid. Как лучше его сделать. Программирование знаю, но за разработку приложения взялся впервые, поэтому даже не знаю, как правильно его построить. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Исин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 8):

Для мессендера Вам понадобиться две вещи - клиент и сервер. Можно, конечно, все разработать с нуля, сделать свой мегакрутой протокол и потратить несколько лет на него.

Поэтому для начала рекомендую взять готовое - [xmpp](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP).

Во-первых, получаете готовые сервер - [eJabber](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ejabberd), [openfire](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openfire) и много других.

Для андроида есть куча готовых библиотек для работы с xmpp - [qsmack](https://code.google.com/p/qsmack/), [Babbler](http://babbler-xmpp.blogspot.com/).

Большинство из них предоставляют готовые методы для подключения, отправки сообщений и много другого.

Также в наличии [документация по протоколу](http://xmpp.org/) и даже частичный [перевод](http://book.itep.ru/4/45/xmpp.htm).

Наличие готовых клиентов поможет в начальной отладке - ведь для тестов нужно хотя бы два клиента.

Сам протокол расширяемый, так что в будущем можно добавить своих штук.